# How can I create IF EXIST clause in my BEFORE INSERT trigger to prevent a duplicate record from being inserted?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```html
 
-- Create a trigger to prevent a student from registering for a section that the student is already 
-- registered for. 
USE College ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  Registration_Before_Insert; 

DELIMITER $$

          
        CREATE TRIGGER Registration_Before_Insert
        BEFORE INSERT ON Registration 
        FOR EACH ROW 
        
        
        
      BEGIN 
        
        DECLARE Studentid INT; 
        
         SELECT COUNT(*) INTO Studentid FROM Registration WHERE StudentID= NEW.StudentID; 
         IF NEW.Studentid= 100 AND NEW.SectionID= 16 THEN 
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'The student is already registered for this section';
  END IF ; 

      END $$

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO Registration(StudentID, SectionID, Grade)
VALUES(100, 16, 4.2); 

INSERT INTO Registration(StudentID, SectionID, Grade)
VALUES(100, 16, 4.2);
```

I am working on creating a BEFORE UPDATE trigger to prevent a student from registering for a section that the student is already registered, but I am not sure how to use the IF EXISTS clause within my trigger to invoke that trigger when I insert the same record twice. Can anyone help me? Here is my code?

Comment: I think you could also achieve this by placing a unique constraint on `(StudentID, SectionID)`.  But since your requirement is a trigger, I won't post this as an answer.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen Can you give me a hint of why the second INSERT goes ahead and inserts the same record again instead displaying the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just need to change the defined variable studentid to something else

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS REGISTRATION;
CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION(StudentID INT, SectionID INT, Grade DECIMAL(10,2));


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  Registration_Before_Insert; 
DELIMITER $$
       CREATE TRIGGER Registration_Before_Insert
        BEFORE INSERT ON Registration 
        FOR EACH ROW 
      BEGIN 
       DECLARE counter INT; 
         SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter FROM Registration WHERE StudentID= NEW.StudentID
                and new.sectionid = sectionid; 
         IF counter > 0 THEN 
                 SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000'
                  SET MESSAGE_TEXT= 'The student is already registered for this section';
        END IF ; 
      END $$

DELIMITER ;

TRUNCATE TABLE REGISTRATION;

INSERT INTO Registration(StudentID, SectionID, Grade)
VALUES(100, 16, 4.2); 

INSERT INTO Registration(StudentID, SectionID, Grade)
VALUES(100, 16, 4.2);
```

Comment: @PSalmon, Why put the TRUNCATE statement. I am not clear about why you put that? Truncate statement deletes the data in the table not the actual table? Your statement works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need truncate - I use it out of habit to ensure that table is empty when I test.